# json delete all values from key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a json like this:

```
{
  "array": [
    {
      "1": null,
      "2": null,
      "3": null,
      "4": null,
      "5": null
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I delete all and have something like this

```
{
    "array": []
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `jsonObject.array = []`?

Answer (score 0):

First, your object is not a valid python dictionary. You'll have to replace null values with None.

Your question is how to clear all elements from a list. You have to choices:

```
mylist.clear()  # Added in python3.(? maybe 5?)
del mylist[:]
```

So in your example:

```
dict={
  "array": [
    {
      "1": None,
      "2": None,
      "3": None,
      "4": None,
      "5": None
    }
  ]
}
dict["array"].clear()
```

Result:

```
>>> dict
{'array': []}
```

Comment: probably that's their json file, before being read into JSON object in python